# Преобразование uint16_t[2] (DWORD считанный из ПЛК) в переменную типа long

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4

Используя QT c libmodbus считываю 2 регистра из ПЛК Delta DVP в переменную  `uint16_t deword_buf[2];`, в итоге получаю: `deword_buf[0] = 0xCB71, deword_buf[1] = 0x04A2`   (hex 04A2CB71 = 77777777 dec). Встроенной функции типа modbus_get_float() в описании libmodbus я не нашел. Подскажите, как преобразовать `uint16_t deword_buf[2];` в `long lSomeVar` ?;

Comment: deword_buf[1] << 16 + deword_buf[0] не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом.

```
( long )deword_buf[1] << 16 | deword_buf[0]
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint16_t deword_buf[] = { 0xCB71, 0x04A2 };     

    std::cout << std::hex << ( ( long )deword_buf[1] << 16 | deword_buf[0] ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
4a2cb71
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, `long lSomeVar = ( long )deword_buf[1] << 16 | deword_buf[0]` , сработало как надо

Comment: @pandora Не за что.

Comment: @pandora отметьте ответ решением - самое лучше спасибо :)